# How to convert a video to 1sec segments using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to convert a video to 1sec long segments. 
Here it is what I've tried

1- Using FFmpeg's -ss -t. It didn't work at all. After some research I found out that due to keyframes positions, it won't solve my problem unless I re-encode the video.

***So, What encoding settings should I use to get seeking work for my case here?***

2- I tried to convert the video to jpgs then join every 30 image together to make a 1sec video -the video has 30fps-

***Actually it works, but it seems very stupid to me, Any smarter ideas here?***

If you were in my shoes, how do you solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Slicing video file into several segments](http://superuser.com/questions/820747/slicing-video-file-into-several-segments).

Comment: I read this question. I tried the solutions but nothing succeed to get 1sec accurate segments.

Comment: The full `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output would be informative.